# NestJS handle timeout

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I have heavy request which takes more than 5 minutes to execute. In my logs I see that NestJS throws every 5 min new request by itself, but I don't see request from browser. As it was recommended I set

```
const app = await app.listen();
app.setTimeout(1800000);
```

and in my rout

```
    @Get('/foo')
    async foo(@Req() req) {
      req.setTimeout(1800000);
      //...
    }
```

but it doesn't work, I see every 5 minutes new request in my logs.
I know, the best solution is making a queue and handle it asynchronously but for this moment I need just increase timeout somehow. Is it possible?

Comment: What is req in your code?

Comment: @Get('/foo')
async foo(@Req() req) {
  req.setTimeout(1800000);
  //...
}

Comment: Well, the foo function will be fired after request in the system. So you cannot set timeout for request, that already here

You should use middleware for that or some framework settings
The better solution is set it on apache / nginx level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was here:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: 300
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use nginx or apache for that.

```
   proxy_read_timeout 5;
   proxy_connect_timeout 5;
   proxy_send_timeout 5;
```

But if you want to set it on express - try this: http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/timeout.html

Comment: The main problem is not increasing timeout, I already increased it in nginx and dont have 502 anymore, but that I see repeated requests every 5 min. By which part they are executed, by nodejs or infra, how do you think?

Comment: The first idea - you should check the cron configs like /etc/crontab.
If there is nothing - try to log the headers.
So, you'll see the client IP / browser and, maybe you`ll understand something=)

Comment: You can also set the rate limit with something like:
https://blog.logrocket.com/rate-limiting-node-js/ or https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/

Comment: For nestjs there are a solution from docs: https://docs.nestjs.com/security/rate-limiting

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

- NestJs: https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors#more-operators
- For express: https://github.com/expressjs/timeout

Example:

```js
import { Injectable, NestInterceptor, ExecutionContext, CallHandler, RequestTimeoutException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError, TimeoutError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, timeout } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class TimeoutInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<any> {
    return next.handle().pipe(
      timeout(5000),
      catchError(err => {
        if (err instanceof TimeoutError) {
          return throwError(() => new RequestTimeoutException());
        }
        return throwError(() => err);
      }),
    );
  };
};
```